Finding the boundary of $\{(x, \sin(\frac{1}{x})) : x > 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.
The following problem was given as an exercise for my course on Intro to Metric Spaces.
Question :-

Define a set $U := \{(x, \sin(\frac{1}{x})) : x > 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Find out the boundary $\partial U$ of the set $U$ with the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To avoid any ambiguity, here is the definition of boundary of a set being used in this particular question
"Let $X$ be a (metric) space and $A \subset X$. A point $x \in X$ is said to be a boundary point of $A$ in $X$ if every open set that contains $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X \setminus A$ non-trivially. The boundary of $A$ in $X$ is the set of boundary points of $A$ in $X$. We denote it by $\partial A$.
"
Intuitively speaking, the answer should be $\partial U$ = $U \cup \{ (0, y) : y \in [-1, 1]\}$, which can be deduced by observing the graph of $f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ on the positive real number domain. (The graph is dense around the region $(-h, h) \times [-1,1] \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ for some sufficiently small positive h).
I know this is not the rigorous proof one would expect from a student undergoing a real analysis course, but I am clueless in how to begin one such construction. Any hints or solutions shall be most helpful.

@julio_es_sui_glace How and where is $U$ open?  Away from $x=0$ it looks to me like a smooth curve.

You are completely right, I was seeing U as a 1-variety

What do you get for $ x=1/(y+2k\pi)$?

Using the definition of boundary that you are working with, we can see first of all that the graph $U = \{ (x, f(x)) : x \in X \}$ of any continuous function $f$ defined on some subset $D$ of $\Bbb{R}$ includes $U$ and no other points $(x, y)$ with $x$ in $D$. For, writing $l_0$ for the vertical line through a point $(x_0, 0)$ with $x_0 \in D$, $l_0$ contains exactly one point of $U$, namely $(x_0, f(x_0))$ and any neighbourhood of that point will meet both $U$ and its complement. For any point say $(x_0, y)$ on $l_0$ with $y \neq f(x_0)$, as $f$ is continuous, for some $\delta>0$, $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < |y - f(x)|$ for all $x$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta$. And then the open disc around the point of radius $\min(\delta, |y - f(x)|)$ will not meet $U$.
In your case $D = (0, \infty)$ and $f(x) = \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ and the above argument tells us all we need to know about the points on $\partial U$ in the open half plane $x > 0$. Now, if the point $(x, y)$ has $x < 0$ then the open disc centred on that point with radius $|x|$ will not meet $G$.
So, we are left with points $(0, y)$ on the $y$-axis. For such a point, if $|y| > 1$, then as all points on $U$ have $y$-coordinate in $[-1, 1]$, the open disc centred on such a point with radius $|y| - 1$ will not meet $U$.
Finally, if a point $(0, y_0)$ on the $y$-axis has $|y| \le 1$, then any open neighbourhood $A$ of the point will meet both $U$ and its complement:

$A$ will meet the complement of $U$ because it contains points $(x, y_0)$ with $x < 0$.
$A$ will meet $U$ because for any $\varepsilon$, $\sin(x)$ takes on every value in $[1, -1]$ as $x$ ranges over $(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}, \infty)$, implying that $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ takes on every value in $[-1, 1]$ as $x$ ranges over $\left(0, \varepsilon\right)$. So as $y \in [-1, 1]$, there are points on $G$ of the form $(x, y_0)$ for arbitrarily small $x$ and our open neighbourhood $A$ will include some (in fact all but finitely many) of those points.

The upshot is that, as you suspected:
$$
\partial U = U \cup \{(0, y) : y \in [-1, 1]\}
$$

Basically, what you want to show is equivalent to $\overline{U} = U \cup \{0\} \times [-1,1]$ since $\mathring U = \varnothing$. How do we show set equalities? just do reciprocal inclusions.
First inclusion: $\overline{U} \subset U \cup \{0\} \times [-1,1]$.
Suppose you have $y_n = (\sin(x_n),\frac{1}{x_n})$ a convergent sequence in $ U^{\mathbb N}$.
Case 1: $\frac{1}{x_n} \to 1/x >0$, then by continuity of $\sin$, $\lim y_n = (\sin(x),1/x) \in U$
Case 2: $1/x_n \to 0$, since $\sin(x_n) \in [-1,1]$, $\lim y_n \in \{0\} \times [-1,1]$.
Second inclusion: $\overline{U} \supset U \cup \{0\} \times [-1,1]$.
Let $y \in [-1,1]$, we set $z = \arcsin (y)$ and the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{z + 2n\pi}$, we have $x_n \to 0$ and $\sin(1/x_n) = \sin(z) = y$ so the sequence $(x_n,\sin(1/x_n))$ converges to $(0,y)$, and since $U \subset \bar{U}$, we have the reverse inclusion.
Remark
$\bar U$ is actually a connected set that is not path connected.
